# How access Redux store on service worker

Tags: reactjs, redux, service-worker

I am using React, Redux and service worker at my application and I want to access the Redux store at my service worker.

My service worker is:

```
function checkCompatibility() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && 'PushManager' in window) {
    console.log('Service Worker and Push is supported');

    navigator.serviceWorker.register('./sw.js')
    .then(function (swReg) {
      console.log('Service Worker is registered', swReg);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error('Service Worker Error', error);
    });
  } else {
    console.warn('Push messaging is not supported');
  }
}

function askForNotification() {
  if (!('Notification' in window)) {
    console.log('This browser does not support desktop notification');
  } else if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
    console.log('Permission granted.');
  } else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied' || Notification.permission === 'default') {
    Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
      if (permission === 'granted') {
        var notification = new Notification('Permissão de Notificação foi Aceita', { icon: '/favicon.png', badge: '/favicon.png' });
      }
    });
  }
}

checkCompatibility();
askForNotification();
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: [Might be relevant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f4KnHNCZcH4)

Comment: This seens to be relevant, thanks

Answer (score 6):

Service Workers are built on top of the Web Worker API. According to the [MDN documentation on Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers):

> workers run in another global context that is different from the current window

Thus the service worker is in a different scope from your Redux code.

However, you might be able to use the [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Client/postMessage) API to communicate between your main application code and the service worker, and pass whatever data you need from Redux via this channel.

Take a look at the code sample [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/service-worker/post-message/index.html) for inspiration.

Comment: Also, remember that you can always have an endpoint handled by the serviceworker to perform the communication, like an API call.

Comment: @FranciscoJordano could you elaborate or post the link to an example where a service worker manages communication? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Service workers cannot communicate directly with the redux store. The way around it is to get it to communicate with your client and use the redux store from the client.
You can do this by using a broadcast channel.

```
// From service-worker.js:
const channel = new BroadcastChannel('sw-messages');
channel.postMessage({msg: 'Hello from SW'});

// From your client pages:
const channel = new BroadcastChannel('sw-messages');
channel.addEventListener('message', event => {
  console.log('Received', event.data);
});
```